# DataBase Connection QSqlQuery::exec: database not open

Tags: sql, oracle, qt

I'am having a problem with my database when i execute the project it shows this error:

```
QSqlQuery::exec: database not open
```

this is my connexion

```
#include "connexion.h"
#include <QSqlError>

bool connexion::CreatConnexion()
{
    QSqlDatabase mydb;
   mydb = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC") ;

   mydb.setDatabaseName("prosit");
   mydb.setUserName("DD");
   mydb.setPassword("DDDD");

bool test;
   if(mydb.open())
   {if (mydb.open())
           test=true;

       else throw QString ("Erreur Paramétres"+mydb.lastError().text());
       return  test;

}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the database is available? Can you connect to it at all?

Comment: @jarlh how can i verify that the database is available?

Comment: For exmaple using a native query tool/window. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh oracle sql developper